# Jquery get list of tr from table by id of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid table that contain a checkBox column .

I want to get list of tr that contain the ID of  checkBox

here is my code

```
 var selected = //list of tr

 var ids = // list of ID of checkBox

for (var index = 0; index < ids.length; index++) {

selected = selected.add(grid.table.find("tr").find("td:first input[id=" + ids[index] +"]").closest("tr"));

  }
```

is there any idea i don't want to use .each to iterate over the table and test one by one

in fire bug i have this message error

```
 unrecognized expression: [id=DT;100]
```

Comment: how are you building the `ids` array? the firebug log is saying that the first element in the array is an id with value `DT;100` which isn't a valid id

Comment: thanx i think that the probleme was the ;  in the id that why i have that error when i change it it gone